# Are there divergent series that cannot be summed up by any method?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there series that diverge in such a way that no known widespread summation method (such as Ramanujan's summation, analytic continuation etc) can ascribe a finite value to such series or the values obtained with different methods do not coincide?

Comment: What about a sequence of random partial sums?

Comment: This question does not make much sense. To say that a divergent series is Cesaro-summable, Ramanujan-summable or anything else, we have to modify the meaning of "convergent". For instance, $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n = -\frac{1}{12}$$ does not hold as a usual identity, but stands for "the value of the analytic continuation of $\sum n^{-s}$ in the point $s=-1$ is $-\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio so what's the point?

Comment: @Anixx: Take a series that is not convergent in any known extended ways, like $\sum_{n\geq 1} e^{\frac{1}{n}+e^{e^n}}$, and call it Anixx-convergent to some particular value, for some reason.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio are u sure it will not be convergent for any methods listed on the wikipedia's page?

Comment: @Anixx: no, I am not sure, but this is not the point. If it is converging by some way, just take some fast-increasing and very irregular function. For instance, I doubt that $\sum_{n\geq 1}H(n)$, where $H$ is the Ackermann function, is "some way" converging.